# VMware Virtualisation - Convert 64bit Windows Server to 32bit VM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, migration, virtualization

I have just started playing around with Vmware sphere and have the hypervisor OS installed on a spare HP ProLiant DL360 G4.

I have created a test virtual machine running Ubuntu which has worked well.

As a test project I wanted to convert a powered on server running Windows Server 2008 64bit into a virtual machine. As soon as I ran the Vmware Go software to start the conversion it became apparent that I cannot run 64bit guest OS's on that particular server.

So, is there a way of migrating 64bit to 32bit during the conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not no, there's very significant differences between the actual code of the 64 and 32 bit versions, no converter will magically change this on the fly.

Comment: Is it possible to migrate the domain settings etc. to a pre-installed 32bit OS VM?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "Domain settings etc". It's possible to create a 32 bit windows 2008 server install and promote it to be a domain controller in the same domain as the 64 bit host, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I see, I forgot that promoting it to a DC would inherit the AD policies etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe there is any way to make that work.

I'm not familiar with the DL360 G4, is that not a 64bit CPU with VT instructions enabled?  Any of the Core2 based Xeons (51xx series or better) should run 64bit guests.

Comment: From what I have read, VT support is not available sadly.